# How do I nest async statements were the execution of the nested statement is dependant on the result of the first?

Tags: c#, sqlite, async-await

I'm trying to build an asynchronous method to get read a record or create it if no matches are found.

I am using the async API provided by SQLite.Net.

This is as far as I have got but I think I'm struggling with the concepts, existingOpponent is always null so the insert is always executed.

```
public async Task<TestEntity> CreateOrGet(string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var existingEntity = await Database.GetConnection(cancellationToken)
        .Table<TestEntity>()
        .Where(o => o.Name == name)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (existingEntity == null)
    {
        var newEntity = new TestEntity() { Name = name };

        var rowCount = await Database.GetConnection(cancellationToken)
            .InsertAsync(newEntity);

        return newEntity;
    }

    return existingEntity;
}
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is `existingEntity`?  The first occurrence of it in your code is in that `if` statement.  Did you really mean to check `existingOpponent` for null?

Comment: I meant existingEntity, that what I get for trying to make my code more generic! Edited.

Comment: They async part look ok to me, I guess the query doesn't work as you except it to. try it without async

Comment: You just await the first call. The method will not continue executing until the awaited call is complete. Your code looks correct to me so I'm going to guess there's a problem inside your query.

Comment: You haven't call SaveChanges() (after InsertAsync) so your entity was never persist to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Was a query problem rather than an async problem.